# Is there any paper or balloon simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I want to know which simulation and what setting i have to give to a balloon flying in air and a paper also so that it should look light weight and if pin it should fly with wind

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to set the scene gravity to a positive value (by default is the usual -9.81), and set a simulation for you baloon...

[image]

then (eg) a rigid body, but also cloth works (you just inverted the "falling" direction, and/or acceleration):

[image]

then, starting the animation with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> your ballon will fly upwards...

[image]

You could also add an empty with wind effect, if strong enough will move your uplifting baloon along the wind direction...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have followed ur step but i got some different result as the balloon gone in z axis faster and i did not get as about adding the empty (have u forgotten to written). And the balloon in ur image look its press at one end. but in my result the balloon gone in z axis and not stop in middle to get that shape

Comment: oh, well add en empty as any other blender objects, use the 3D viewport "add" menu or a shortcut, is the same. Then add "wind" to it. Of course you have to experiment a bit to get the desired effect, this is quite normal with simulations... and you can use a smaller gravity value to get things go slower... maybe describe better what you are aiming too, and some more help can be added (here or in a new question)..